# "fortune -o" (offensive fortunes) no fortunes found

Tags: bash, fortune

I downloaded fortunes but I can't get any offensive fortunes.

From [fortune man page](https://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune)

> `-o` Choose only from potentially offensive aphorisms.  The -o option is ignored if a fortune directory is specified.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt install fortune-mod
$ sudo apt install fortunes-min
$ sudo apt install fortunes
$ fortune -o
No Fortunes Found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the results of `apt-cache search --names-only fortunes`, it looks like the package you need (at least for offensiveness in the English language) is `fortunes-off`

```
fortunes-off - Data files containing offensive fortune cookies
```

To install it run:

```
sudo apt install fortunes-off
```